# .NET's SqlParameters in PHP

Tags: php, sql-injection, parameter-passing

What is the counterpart of `Command.SqlParameters.AddWithValue()` of .NET in PHP? I want to avoid SQL injection, I just wonder if PHP already has the same method aside from escaping strings thru `mysql_real_escape()`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)'s [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) method and [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

The difference between  the two is `bindParam()` binds a reference to a variable. The variable value can change without having to re-bind the parameter. This is particularly useful in loops.

`bindValue()` simply binds a static value to a parameter.

Comment: Wow! It's more than what I need, that PDO also has transactions, commit and rollback. Thanks! By the way, I don't agree with execution of query in each iteration of loop. He he.

Comment: @domanokz It's just handy to know. Some DBs will only allow a single set of values in an insert statement. If you have an array or collection of entries to insert, it's nice and clean to bind once to the variables and execute the inserts while looping